# Can Swift switch statements have another switch in a case?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I've looked at all of Apple's documentation, as well as multiple end-user blogs and similar... and not one single example of a `switch` statement with multiple lines in the `case`, let alone another `switch`. I tried a couple of different syntaxes, but no go, it always complains about an unused closure. Is this possible?

Comment: please can you show your code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course it's possible

```
enum Alphabet {
  case Alpha, Beta, Gamma
}

enum Disney {
  case Goofy, Donald, Mickey
}

let foo : Alphabet = .Beta
let bar : Disney = .Mickey

switch foo {
case .Alpha, .Gamma: break
case .Beta:
  switch bar {
  case .Goofy, .Donald: break
  case .Mickey: print("Mickey")
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup. The key is the curly braces.

Comment: No, it's not. I'm not sure what it was, but some sort of syntax problem somewhere. All I did was re-arrange the lines, not even edit them, and suddenly it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, nested switch statements and multiple lines in the cases are both possible.

```
let firstNumber = 0
let secondNumber = 3

switch firstNumber {

case 0:

    switch secondNumber {

    case 0:
        print("First and second numbers are 0")
    default:
        print("First number is 0, second number is not")

    }

default:

    print("First number is not 0")

}
```